# Adding style to my element via code

Tags: c#, wpf

How can I add a style from my ResourceDictionary to an element programtically?

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="Learning.App"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Learning">
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="LabelTituloEstiloPadrao">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="40,20,0,0" />
    </Style>    
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Label l = new Label();
    // Add Style in my label l
    StackHorarios.Children.Add(l);
}
```

How can I add the *LabelTituloEstiloPadraostyle* to my label l via source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
l.Style = (Style) App.Current.Resources["LabelTituloEstiloPadrao"];
```

note this will throw an exception if the resource key is not found

Comment: help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659165/adding-eventsetter-methods-in-class

Answer (score 1):

Set the style in your `MainWindow.xaml` file, like so:

```
<Label Name ="Example" Content="Hello World" Style="{StaticResource LabelTituloEstiloPadrao}">
```

Or if you would like to do it in the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file:

```
l.Style = (Style)(this.Resources["LabelTituloEstiloPadrao"]);
```

Comment: both methods fail. 1st fails, because Label doesn't exist in xaml. 2nd fails, becuase this.Resources doesn't contain requested resource