# Getting Error CS1061 on EventSetter of App.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, eventhandler

I'm trying to create an element by my code and associate a style for it, also associating its EventSetter, the style works perfectly but when I try to run the function it does not work.

**App.xaml**

```
<Application x:Class="Learning.App"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Learning">
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Label" x:Key="LabelTituloEstiloPadrao">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="40,20,0,0" />

<EventSetter Event="MouseLeftButtonUp" Handler="lbl_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
<EventSetter Event="MouseRightButtonUp" Handler="lbl_MouseRightButtonUp"/>

    </Style>    
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public ViewConfigAgendaDin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ConfigInicial();

            Label l = new Label();
            lblTeste.Style = (Style)App.Current.Resources["LabelTituloEstiloPadrao"];

            StackHorarios.Children.Add(l);
        }

        private void lbl_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Right");
        }

        public void lbl_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Left");
        }
```

when the application is being built, two errors are fired into the EventSetter

> Error CS1061 "App" does not contain a setting for
>   "lbl_MouseLeftButtonUp" and could not find any "lbl_MouseLeftButtonUp"
>   extension method that accepts a first argument of type "App" (is there
>   a usage directive or assembly reference missing?)

The same error also happens for the right event, how can I do to implement these two methods in my class where I am using this without giving problems?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you get **Error CS1061** when a method is inaccessible from XAML.

Most common cases are:

- event handler is not declared in code-behind
- XAML's `x:Class` tag not matching the actual name of the class
- name of the method not matching the `Handler` of event setter
- incorrect handler method signature
- using a `private` method in the `base` class instead of `protected`
- a need for restarting the visual studio in rare cases

---

Looking at the XAML code, your class name is `Learning.App`

```
<Application x:Class="Learning.App"
```

But the code behind in which the event handlers are declared is `ViewConfigAgendaDin`

```
public class ViewConfigAgendaDin
```

You can't put the event handlers anywhere and expect the compiler to find them by itself. Because the handler is used in `App.XAML`, you need to **Move the event handlers to `App.xaml.cs`** and it will be good to go.

If you need them to be in `ViewConfigAgendaDin` class, either define the `Style` in `ViewConfigAgendaDin.xaml` or call a method in `ViewConfigAgendaDin.xaml.cs` from `App.xaml.cs`

### Edit:

For example:

ViewConfigAgendaDin.xaml:

```
<ViewConfigAgendaDin 
    xmlns:v="clr-namespace:MY_NAMESPACE">
...
    <Label Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type v:ViewConfigAgendaDin}}}" 
           Style="{StaticResource LabelTituloEstiloPadrao}"/>
...
</ViewConfigAgendaDin>
```

ViewConfigAgendaDin.xaml.cs:

```
public void MyMethodForRightClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Right");
}
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
private void lbl_MouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    ((sender as Label).Tag as ViewConfigAgendaDin).MyMethodForRightClick(sender, e);
}
```

---

Another way to handle this situation is to avoid code-behind altogether. Instead, make use of **MVVM** and **Command** Binding. You can easily bind any event to a command using **Interactions**

Comment: but for example I declare my EventSetter in my app.xaml I can not create the methods in the class that will use this style? in this method in question lbl_MouseLeftButtonUp I would have to use a datatable that is in the ViewConfigAgendaDin class, as I can use it in that class

Comment: no you can't create the methods in `ViewConfigAgendaDin`. it must be in the same class as the xaml. but you can call any `ViewConfigAgendaDin` method you want from `App.xaml.cs` see my edit.

Comment: Now you can understand, this method is like an interface and I can use it also in my ViewConfigAgendaDin.xaml?
`private void lbl_MouseRightButtonUp (object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
     // x var global
    Label l = (sender) Label; x = l.Name; MessageBox.Show (x);
}`

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment. you can call any method you want from anywhere. but the event handler `lbl_MouseRightButtonUp` **must** be declared in app.xaml.cs

Comment: I assumed that you can't move the `Style` to `ViewConfigAgendaDin.xaml`. so you need to move the event handler to app.xaml.cs

Comment: please take a look at the answer again. I made a few changes.